# Test Javascript class constructor that calls own method with mocha?

Tags: javascript, node.js, unit-testing, mocha.js

Can I get a tip on how to test and/or stub a Javascript class constructor that calls its own method? Or, can I write this differently so it is testable? It works well but when testing, it crashes mocha.

```
// foo.js
var foo = function() {
    // The line that crashes mocha.
    this.bar((err, response) => {});
};

foo.prototype.bar = (callback) => {
    // return err or response
};
module.exports = new foo();

// unittest.js
describe('foo', function() {
    it('return error', function() {
        const foo = require('foo');
        foo.bar(function(error, response) {
            // test works fine if i remove
            // constructor/line/this.bar...
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: You are getting an error because you are using `this` inside of an arrow function. Arrow functions do *not* bind their own `this`. So try using an anonymous function instead.

Comment: @FrenchMajesty, thank you. The actual code does use an anonymous function. I've updated the example above to reflect this more accurately.

Comment: The code you now show in your question runs without any error whatsoever. You need to turn this into a [mcve]. Please run it before putting it up to make sure it reproduces the problem you have.

Comment: @CharlieWilson What error message are you getting?